# Create-reac- app command is not working properly and hang at a point

Tags: reactjs

I am trying command npx create-react-app folder name. but it stuck after saying installing react and other things.

Screenshot of the issue -
[image]
I have the latest version of node and npm.

Comment: I think it would take a couple of minutes since it has to download the dependencies and install them in node_modules. I think you would just need to give it some time.

Comment: Thanks for Replying @NI

I am waiting from last 1 hour

Comment: Is your system has HDD or SSD?

Comment: HDD, I didn't get the problem, As I have another pc, same config , and same node and npm version, on that cretae-react-app is working fine in first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling npm and re-install it, or try updating your node js.

Comment: I have installed latest version. but still not working.

Comment: are able to see the folder gets created but without public or app folder ?

Comment: Problem is related to npm audit and npm fund I think, I really don't know anything about both of these

Comment: not sure, I was facing the same but when I had no options left I did OS installation after trying lot of times, byt may be this article can help you I believe, please have a look. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Comment: Thank you for sharing this article. I will check and hope this solve my problem